# How to convert less files into css in Webpack?

Tags: gulp, less, webpack

I am new to webpack. Want to know how do we lessify or convert less files into css using webpack, like we use cssify plugin in gulp.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455863/webpack-build-less-files-output-one-css-minify-file

Answer (score 1):

You use webpack's [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader) (along with the css-loader and probably the style-loader) and `require()` the less file the same way you would a javascript module. See [Using Loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html) for more info on how loaders work in webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Extract-Text-Webpack-Plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). Basically, webpack is a JS module bundler so (as far as I know) there's no way to compile less directly into css. Instead, you can 'load' less file into js using something like [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader) and other loaders, and extract text to make separate css file using plugin.